# using Rails root in seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my seeds.rb, I'm doing some file upload cleanup and want to access RAILS_ROOT but doesn't seem to work. Calling:

```
puts RAILS_ROOT
```

doesn't work. How would I access this?

```
puts Rails.root
```

does work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAILS_ROOT is [deprecated](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html) - you should use Rails.root instead